# VLC 3.x doesn't see half of files

Tags: 16.04, vlc

Here is what I observe:

[image]

As you see, I have directories like `lib32` and `NAS` on my drive, but `VLC` doesn't display it in file open dialog. I also can't play any file from such place by specifying filename: `VLC` says file not found.

What is it and how to fix?

Comment: How did you installed VLC? Please add output of `apt-cache policy vlc`, `which vlc`, `snap list | grep -i vlc`, `flatpak list | grep -i vlc` to the question.